# MySQL Query to get Similar likes

Tags: mysql, join

I am designing a simple architecture where i have a table which stores users and some elements that they like so my table structure is something like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | like_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       4 |
|       2 |       2 |
|       4 |       4 |
|       4 |       3 |
|       5 |       4 |
|       6 |       7 |
|       7 |       5 |
|      34 |       6 |
|       3 |       8 |
|       2 |       3 |
|       2 |       5 |
|       1 |       3 |
|       1 |      10 |
|       1 |      12 |
|       2 |      10 |
+---------+---------+
```

Now what i will have is `id` of any user (lets say `user_id` = 1 ) and i want a query to get all the other users who have similar Likes as that of 1.

So in the Output for user_id = 1 will be :

```
+---------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
|  users_with_common_likes  |   no_of_common_likes   |  common_likes  |
+---------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
|      4                    |       2                |      3,4       |
|      2                    |       2                |      3,10      |
|      5                    |       1                |        4       |
+---------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

**What I have achieved :**
I can do this using a sub-query as below :

```
SELECT user_id
FROM  `user_likes` 
WHERE  `like_id` 
IN (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `like_id` ) 
   FROM user_likes
   WHERE user_id =1
)
AND user_id !=1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However this query is not giving all the users,it misses the user_id = 2 which has like id 3 in common with user_id=1.

and i cant figure out how to find the remaining 2 columns.

Also I feel that this is not the best way to to this as this table will contain thousands of data and it may effect system performance.

> I would like to do this with a single Mysql Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes a PK formed on user_id,like_id...

```
SELECT y.user_id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(y.like_id) likes
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.like_id = x.like_id 
   AND y.user_id <> x.user_id 
 WHERE x.user_id = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY y.user_id;
```